# Visual Studio - "The application was unable to start correctly"

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, runtime-error

When I try to run my Visual C++ application, a box comes up saying "The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b)." The only output is

Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file

But all of those files exist...which makes me think that its not the cause of the application's error. With no other output, I don't know what could be wrong. If anyone knows what I could check for or how to fix it, I would be grateful.

Comment: Use the search feature here on SO for that error code (0xc000007b). There are a lot of possible duplicates and solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Few blueprints:

1. Rebuild the application, including all dependent DLLs, and try again.
2. Ensure all dependent DLLs, services (like MSMQ) are available and running.
3. Check if one of your DLLs  `DllMain` is returing failure, which causes the application to start. OS won't start, if any of DLL returns failure while initializing.
4. Ensure you have correct CRT/MFC versions for the Debug/Release DLL you are using, or have linked other DLLs/EXE with.
5. Use Dependency Walker to find out of any DLL is missing, not found, or of different platform.

Answer (score 1):

A colleague of min told me he read once that **re-building** opencv should fix this. Which worked for me. Notice I'm using opencv1.1(x86) under a win7 64-bit cpu.

Best of luck.
Hasan.